# Using Popen to launch another script and send input

Tags: python, popen

I have two scripts one just asks for input then prints the input. The other one launches the script. It is only half working and I was hoping someone could shed some light on the issue.

test.py

```
import subprocess

process = subprocess.Popen('python test2.py', shell=False,
                           stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                           stderr=None)
process.stdin.write("test\r\n".encode('utf-8'))
process.stdin.flush()

result = process.stdout.readline()[:-2].decode('utf-8')
print(result)
while result != "":
    result = process.stdout.readline()[:-2].decode('utf-8')
    print(result)
```

test2.py

```
s=input("input here:")
print(s)
```

expected output:

```
input here:test
test
```

actual output:

```
input here:test
```

Comment: From the actual output you can see that something is populating and the word test is being written by stdin but I'm not seeing the print(s) part of the script.

Comment: The actual output I get is a traceback caused by `NameError: name 'test' is not defined` followed by a line `input her`.

Comment: Well then I'm not sure what needs to be modified for this to function.

Comment: Actually, when I switched to Python 3, it works correctly for me. What version are you using?

Comment: The output was as expected? I'm using python 3.5.1 from Anaconda 4.0.0 and working in the spyder IDE

Comment: I'm using Python 3.5.2 on Windows 7 (no Anaconda). Try running the main script, `test.py`, from the command-line if you aren't already.

Comment: 'C:\Users\Documents\test>python test.py
input here:test


'
It is still not printing the input

Comment: Think I figured it out: You're got `result = process.stdout.readline()[:-2].decode('utf-8')` _twice_ in the main `test.py` script.

Comment: Python 2: `input()` will perform an `eval()` on the text received, thus the NameError.  In Python 3, `input()` is safer, and works like `raw_input()` in Python 2.

Comment: Note that the input is not echoed.  If you are sitting at a terminal and were to run 'python test2.py', the *terminal* would echo your input as you typed it. That would show the word "test" twice. The test.py program will send the word "test" through the pipe; it does not print it to stdout. The test2.py program prints the input once.  Thus the output "input here:test" is correct.

Comment: Thank you dsh that makes sense to me and I would have never figured that out. How can I capture the stdin and stdout pipe to show what test2.py is receiving from test.py?

Comment: I don't think you can "capture stdin". But since you control it, you could print everything you write to it.  You can create a function that will print the argument then write it to the pipe.  Then use that function to send data to the pipe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the input is not echoed. If you are sitting at a terminal and were to run 'python test2.py', the *terminal* would echo your input as you typed it. That would show the word "test" twice. Your test.py program sends the word "test" through the pipe; it does not print it to stdout. The test2.py program prints the input once. Thus the output "input here:test" is correct.